# Pseudo-Orientação a Objeto em C e alocação Dinâmica

Tags: c, alocação, dinâmico

Eu estou tentando fazer um campo minado em c usando ncurses.h e quando vou fazer o vetor de "objetos bomba" o Linux diz que não consegue encontrar o espaço de memória em que estão os valores das bombas:

PS: não eu não posso usar c++

```
typedef struct Bomb
{
    int x, y;
} Bomb;

Bomb* setBomb(int i){

    Bomb* newBomb = malloc(sizeof(Bomb));

    srand(time(NULL) / i);
    newBomb->x = rand() % i * (i + 1);

    srand(time(NULL) * i);
    newBomb->y =  rand() % i * (i + 1);

    return newBomb;
}

Bomb** setBombs(WINDOW* win, int amountBombs)
{

    Bomb** bombs = malloc(sizeof(Bomb) * amountBombs);

    for(int i = 0; i < amountBombs; ++i)
    {
        bombs[i] = setBomb(i);
    }

    drawBomb(win, bombs, amountBombs);

    return bombs;
}

int drawBomb(WINDOW* win, Bomb** bomb, int amount)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        mvwprintw(win, bomb[0]->y, bomb[0]->x, "O");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrumei o erro: o problema estava no srand(), eu estava fazendo com q ele gerasse um numero de ponto flutuante e isso n é permitido